# FFMPEG Slow Video and Audio by Half

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I am using the latest version of FFMPEG and am trying to slow video and audio by half

This is the best I could come up with

```
./ffmpeg.exe -i "C:/ffmpeg/input.mp4" -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=1.5*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=0.5[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" "C://ffmpeg/output.mp4"
```

But the audio and video are not being slowed down at the same rate.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to slow to 50% i.e. 1/2, it should be `setpts=2*PTS` & `atempo=0.5`.
If you mean to slow by 50% i.e. 2/3, it should be `setpts=1.5*PTS` & `atempo=0.6667`.